# Send an email on drop down value changed using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am trying to link an email address that corresponds with a name in a dropdownlist on a website which works kinda like a helpdesk. 
So for example, if I selected "John" then John should receive a 'notification' like mail saying that a ticket has been logged. 
However, everything works, I am just looking for a piece of code or a tutorial which links a email address to the name in the ddlist.

I am working with VS2012, Sql Server and it's on a normal webform NOT a MVC Application.

Can anyone help with a tutorial maybe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The email id you will have to keep with name somewhere? From where you are getting the names from database?

Comment: Uhm yeah, I guess if I were to create a couple of users and assign those to the name. But now again, the user information would be a username, password, and his email address. So again, how do you link this email address to a name displayed in a ddl?

Comment: @starcatcher: have a look at my basic example. Hope you will get what you want. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helps you. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a simple example where you have details like:

```
    Name  Email
-------------------------
    a     a@a.com
    b     b@b.com
    c     c@c.com
```

Now bind the dropdown and set Name as a Text Field and Email as a ValueField. Here I am displaying static dropdown and guess that you want to send an email when value from the dropdown is changed.

So in your aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlStaff" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStaff_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a@a.com"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b@b.com"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="c" Value="c@c.com"></asp:ListItem>
    </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and your code behind would be:

```
protected void ddlStaff_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ddlStaff.SelectedValue))
    {
        var emailAddress = this.ddlStaff.SelectedValue;

        // Code to send an email
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

- [How to bind dropdown list from database in ASP.net C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/binding-dropdownlist-with-database-and-display-data-in-gridv/)
- [How to send an email in ASP.net c#](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/11/introduction-this-article-i-will.html)

Comment: hi again, sorry, but how do you implement the ddlStaff_OnSelectedIndexChanged inside say a "Submit button"? I'm trying to make this as simple as possible.

Comment: you mean you want to send an email by clicking some button ?

Comment: yes, for instance this button has to have two functions. It's updating the data to the database, AND sending the mail to the selected person. I did the first part, now I'd like to know if you can code the email into the ddlStaff_OnSelectedIndexChnged and then use this in the button somehow?